# Переход на другую страницу при нажатии кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf

При попытке навигации (навигация в окно page2.xaml):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Выкидывает это :

> Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства
>   "NavigationService.Navigate(Uri)" требуется ссылка на объект.

Как исправить?

Comment: ссылаетесь на тутор, дак приводите ссыль на него.

Comment: @teran

http://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread174427.html

Answer (score 3):

Получите экземпляр службы навигации:

```
NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
```

и затем выполняйте переход:

```
nav.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

При исполнении данного кода выпадает ошибка

`System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
`

Comment: Ок, а где вы page свою выводите? Во frame? Приведите разметку окна в вопросе